# timeout a blocking function call, no threads, no external libs

Tags: c, network-programming

I have code similar to this (very simplified):

```
char *data, *ack;
...
while (<not done>) {
    sendData(data+offset);
    receiveACK(ack);
// <<<What I want to do>>>
//  if (ack == <bad> || <receiveACK() TIMEOUT>)
//      continue;
//
    ... 
    offset += SPACING;
}
```

The problem is that sendData() and receiveACK() are blocking black boxes I HAVE TO use.

All I want is to trigger sendData() with the same input again if I fail to receive an ACK in a given timeframe. How should I do this?

NOTE: Threads are not an option.

EDIT: A bit of background on sendData() and receiveACK(). They do network communication. sendData() tries to send data and fails if it doesn't work (no problem here). The issue is that on the other end, ACKs are only send if sequence and checksum are correct. In other words: data error => no ACK. Now, receiveACK() just waits for traffic and interprets it. If there's no traffic (no ACK), it just keeps on waiting, forever if necessary ... which is why I'm trying to build the timeout around it.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `sendData()` does always return, try adding

```
alarm(<number of seconds>);
```

just before the call to

```
receiveACK(ack);
```

If you are lucky the `SIGALRM` signal raised after `<number of seconds>` will make `receiveACK();` return.

(This assumes `SIGALRM` is not blocked/ignored.)

Comment: Can you elaborate on why SIGALRM will make receiveACK() return? What would the signal handler need to be?

Comment: @McEnroe The alarm handler doesn't need to do anything, but when it fires, all currently blocked system calls will return -1 with `errno == EINTR`. Of course some libraries just loop on this condition ...

Comment: So just calling receiveACK(ack) as follows should do it?  
    siginterrupt(14, 1);
    alarm(2);
    receiveACK(ack);
    alarm(0); 
    siginterrupt(14, 0);

Comment: @mcenroe: Yes, this **might** help. It depends on how the receiveACK handles this case internally. It might return, as well as it could just loop and continue waiting for the ACK to arrive.

Answer (score 2):

If those functions aren't black boxes, use select or poll on whatever socket you're checking in receiveAck, to set the timeout you want.  If you get the ack in time, move to the next packet.  If you timeout, resend.

If they're true black boxes, you're screwed.  You'd need more functionality from your library.  Although maybe you can do something to force the read to fail with EINTR if you're on a linux box.  Select of poll is the right solution though.